# Rails 4 strong params confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm trying to use strong params in Rails 4.1 and failing hard.

```
# Some request params
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
  order: {
    shipping_method: '03',
    line_items_attributes: [{
      sale_id: "12847",
      qty: "12"
    }]
  }
})

# try to permit them all
params.permit(:order).permit(
  :shipping_method,
  {
    line_item_attributes: [
      :sale_id,
      :qty,
    ]
  }
)

# Unpermitted parameters: order
# => {}
```

I expect to be able to permit all those params.

Why am I getting that warning, and why do I get an empty hash as the return value?

---

It seems `require` is more helpful, however I still can't get my nested array of hashes

```
params.require(:order).permit(
  :shipping_method,
  {
    line_item_attributes: [
      :sale_id,
      :qty,
    ]
  }
)

# Unpermitted parameters: line_items_attributes
# => {"shipping_method"=>"03"}
```

Comment: I believe it should be `params.require(:order).permit(...)`. Notice the require instead of permit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `params.require(:order)` and not `params.permit(:order)`

Check this out in **[Rails Docs : Action Controller Parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html)**

Your code should look like:

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
  order: {
    shipping_method: '03',
    line_items_attributes: [{
      sale_id: "12847",
      qty: "12"
    }]
  }
})
```

and after that

```
params.require(:order).permit(
  :shipping_method,
  {
    line_items_attributes: [
      :sale_id,
      :qty,
    ]
  }
)
```

**NOTE**: You need to permit `line_items_attributes` (Notice **plural items**) and NOT `line_item_attributes` (Not **singular item**). (Assuming you have `1-M association` between `Order` and `LineItem`)

Comment: So `permit` does not drill in to the hash, but `require` does? In this case `params[:order]` would be required, so that should be ok. But it now coughs up `Unpermitted parameters: line_items_attributes`

Comment: Oh my. God dammit. Nice catch on the typo... *(embarassed)* Maybe it's time for a break. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has to do with the fact that you are calling `permit` twice when defining your accepted parameters. The way the strong parameters work is that you must `require` the parameter that corresponds to the object you are trying to build (in your case, `:order`). You can then chain this method with a call to `permit`, which accepts a comma-separated list of parameters corresponding to the params you wish to accept for your object:

```
params.require(:order).permit(:shipping_method, :line_items_attributes,...)
```

If you wish to accept nested params, you must specify them as an array within the `permit` method:

```
params.require(:order).permit(:shipping_method, 
                              line_items_attributes: [:sale_id, :qty])
```

Check out the [full documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) for more info.